# SSL Security man-in-the-middle attack

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

Alot of debate about this but one thing isnt clear to me.
Can't an ISP intercept the connection between the client and the server?
Like when the ISP intercept the initial process of SSL connection, the ISP WILL RESPOND TO THE CLIENT and not the server? pretending its from the server.
Therefor the ISP can be a perfect man-in-the-middle with the power of reading AND modifying data whenever they want, is that correct?

Comment: No, because ISP doesn't hold a certificate that matches the website you are trying to access. Your browser would display some "connection untrusted" error page.

Comment: Also, security.SE would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because the ISP doesn't hold a *private key* that matches the certificate at the server you are trying to access. So unless you aren't checking the peer certificate, i.e. you are accepting the ISP's own certificate instead of the website's certificate, it is impossible for him to masquerade as the endpoint.